# Performance improvement while sending large file to multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets, operating-system

I want to send file to at-least 100 clients.One file is of 225MB. I did some testing and i am not able to achieve even 80-90% of available bandwidth for sending file.

While sending file to only one client : 8 seconds

For 2 clients : 45-50 seconds  (this is a dramatic increase)

And it keeps on increasing up to 30 Minutes for 50 clients.

Network bandwidth is 1Gbps. Which means i can achieve speed more than 100MB/s.

Here is the part of my code related to this:

```
            totalSize = (int) file.length();
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setContentLength(totalSize);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" + fileName + "."+extension+"\"");

            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            OutputStream os = nresponse.getOutputStream();
            int byteRate = DmConstants.BYTE_RATE;

            byte[] buff = new byte[DmConstants.BYTE_RATE];              
            int a = -1;         
            while((a = is.read(buff)) != -1) 
            {
                // a is the number of bytes ACTUALLY read, so 
                // when we write, that's the number of bytes to write
                os.write(buff,0,a);     
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            is.close();
```

`BYTE_RATE` is the buffer size which is 1MB. How can I improve the performance?

While copying the files I am able to get around 125MB/s which looks fine.
multiple read/write operation is taking lots of time I guess(sBYTE_RATEyscall).
Any way to reduce it?

Comment: Have you considered using UDP?  Are the clients all on the local network or are they further afield?

Comment: All of them are in Local network only.

Comment: Then you could broadcast the files using UDP; that is, write the file once and deliver to all 100 clients in a single shot.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: @ChrisK You should point in your comment that UDP does not assure you that all of the packets will be received by the clients... Myself I would try with multithreading and/or async IO.

Comment: You can reverse the data transfer model from server-push to client-pull. You'd upload the data file to a shared secured ftp server, broadcast the download link and clients would download it from the file server themselves, leaving the load-balancing, chunked-download-with-restart-resume and other disk I/O optimizations on the server

Comment: If you send to 50 clients, how many times do you read the file, (because you only need to read it once).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of techniques that you can use to improve performance:

1. memory map the file that you are loading; this is a technique used by varnish and it reduces the number of OS context switches required to load the data from disk as well as works very efficiently with CPU prefetching. it also means that you do not have to keep reloading the same data over and over, and you will not have to close the file immediately as the OS will handle the paging very efficiently for you.
2. avoid copying the bytes between data structures, both within your program and the OS. It is possible to repoint a NIO bytes buffer to the bytes that have been memory mapped to a file, thus getting the bytes to the network adapter much much quicker than otherwise possible.
3. research tuning the network settings/driver for your OS.
4. broadcast files to multiple clients rather than keep resending the same file over and over, this will require more work from you to ensure that the data arrives correctly but on modern network hardware packet loss is very low (until the network saturates and the packet loss falls off of a cliff - which sounds worse than it really is, get this balanced well and it is worth the effort). The advantage here is that you can scale the number of clients, eg 1 file in 7 seconds to 1 client or 7s to 100 clients; it is all the same.  The network will handle the distribution of the files by delivering the packets to multiple machines simultaneously.
5. if speed is really really important, then there are specialized network cards/drivers out there that support bypassing the OS kernel and maps the network buffers straight into the user address space; I mention this primarily for completeness as I am not aware of anybody outside of the low latency space that is actively using this technique.